Why are so many professors' websites out of date?
Inspired by comments and answers to Do professors normally explicitly state on their web page that they aren't taking new applicants?

Given that most professors' websites are years out of date, empirically ...

Why are most professors' websites years out of date? What is stopping them from updating their websites?

Comments and answers-in-comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion or containing answers will be removed.

As an example, my "official professorial" web page is on my college's website. The institution formally controls what's published there, such that any change has to go through multiple layers of administrative oversight, approval, handoff to technical staff, ticket pipeline -- and then likely iterations on fixing errors that pop up through that broken-telephone game -- before being actually live on the site.
It's so much work, and uncertain to actually succeed, that many staff and departments just give up and don't bother except in cases of really huge overhauls. Frequently by the time you get around to making a change, the whole process has been reorganized, and then you need to add in some advance research to find out who the current lead contact is, what the process is, how they expect the change to be communicated, etc. I think if I were to ask my department staff right now, they wouldn't know how changes can be made.
Over time, anything that feels like PR gets more and more tightly-gripped by the college administration, and therefore harder to change, I'd say.

This is exactly the problem at my institution as well.  My solution is to have a personal website of my own - it is not very up to date either, but that is because I spend too much of my time on admin and teaching to actually do anything worth posting there.  My official university web page has a conspicuous link to my personal one.

Academics crave freedom. When that is quashed, they just move on to an area where they have it. I used to have a well-maintained and informative, even if not stylish, webpage. Then we moved to a corporate unified page which is much harder to maintain, and near impossible to automate content for. And that's that.

@CaptainEmacs - I'm not sure it is freedom per se, just a level of hassle that totally negates any perceived benefit.

@JonCuster I assume you mean "avoid lack of freedom"? The way it's written, I cannot semantically parse your comment in the context of mine.

I don't think that 'lack of freedom' impacts the decision to stop updating, more that bureaucratic obstacles provide enough friction to abandon the issue.

@JonCuster: for many, I think it’s both — the bureaucratic obstacles provide friction; they also restrict our freedom in what we can put up there, which reduces our motivation to overcome the freedom.

@JonCuster I actually agree with most of your statement. Except that enough friction becomes equivalent to lack of freedom.

@CaptainEmacs - I try to keep a distinction between intentional and unintentional (yet often highly predictable) outcomes. Censoring your institutional website restricts your freedom. Bureaucratic friction is part and parcel of human organizations. Saying it restricts your freedom is attributing the result to malice.

@JonCuster A seat belt restricts my freedom, and I do not attribute it to malice. A bureaucracy may have good reasons to restrict my freedom or it may be just due to misalignment, due to lazy bureaucrats, due bureaucrats that do not like to take responsibility, due to power-players or due to actual antagonism.  There is a whole spectrum, ranging from the benevolent to the malign. But it still may restrict freedom. It is substantially more easy to tolerate the cases closer to the former part of the spectrum, but it does not change the situation on the ground.

The well-oiled efficiency machine of academia...

This answer makes a good point but in many cases, in my experience, a professor's website is a personal website (sometimes hosted by the university but controlled by the prof, sometimes not) and these websites too are often years out of date.

@Mentalist "of academia" -> "of by far most large organizations". Here, fixed that for you.

Various reasons:

Sadly, course content is becoming a walled garden. When I was a student, many professors had a page with their own course notes; today the same course notes are more often hosted on a Google Classroom, Microsoft Teams class, or closed Moodle instance, and they are not accessible from people outside the university. I see this as a big loss.

The incentives in having a personal website are typically tied to hiring. A website is a business card; once you have tenure, you are swamped with other responsibilities and updating your page becomes less important.

Another thing worth pointing out is that today having a website is the exception, not the norm. Which other category of people has a personal website, today? I mean a true self-hosted website, not just a social media page. Programmers, mostly, but it could be argued that for them it's also a business card to get a job; it just gets updated longer because they job-hop more.



Indeed. At my univ, in math, there is more and more pressure to put any course materials into some proprietary software... which does not allow access to anyone not registered for the course. E.g., I cannot see my colleagues' course notes or syllabi! But I do still maintain all my notes of all sorts on-line, in PDF, linked-to from plain-HTML pages. I think I'm somewhat "grandfathered-in"... and, also, I do not know what to plan for after I retire, etc...

"Sadly, course content is becoming a walled garden." - I've also been observing this trend in the Netherlands. It's not only sad in general, I feel it's also actively worse for students. Since students usually only get access to the course information when the course starts, it has become harder to assess a course's content before enrolling :(

@paulgarrett For standard courses like calculus where I don't write notes, indeed I don't put info on my public webpage anymore and just use the university LMS.  But for advanced courses where I write up notes, I still use my public webpage.  I don't see this as a huge loss of resources, though I realize not everyone's like us.

@paulgarrett Of course there is still the persistency issue for informal notes etc you mention.  One option is to post things to AMS Open Math Notes.

@Kimball That option is available for math only, while the problem is broader. And unfortunately AMS is quite cold on open-licensing matters, so it is very unclear what one can or cannot do with those notes. The website states that visitors are "encouraged to download and use any of these materials as teaching and research aids", but the FAQ states that "Copyright for all notes resides with the original author", granting no rights.

I share the "walled garden" concern.  Between spring and summer terms, I've put the only course I'm currently teaching fully online and fully public on YouTube.  (If you care, search in YouTube for IT3123.)

@paulgarrett I don't see why any professor couldn't post the content to their personal site first, with each PDF containing the URL to the original source and a CC-0, CC-BY, etc. badge, and then deliver that content to the university (unaltered). If they want exclusivity, the uni should have to pay for such a contract, I think.

@paulgarrett get all your pages and notes into the Internet Archive, please! That way, if you win the lottery (or 'catch' the proverbial bus) and no longer maintain your site, then it will still be there for all of us to benefit.

(@DavidRoberts, thanks for your encouragement... such things are, indeed, an issue for the future...)

@paulgarrett how does that "pressure" manifest itself where you are? Several years ago I finally started using the internal LMS here as the place to post basic details about my courses that are of no interest to outsiders (e.g., syllabi, problem sets, and course announcements) and only because more and more students in my classes were expecting things to be in the LMS since all their non-math classes were using it. But I never felt any push to put my course notes behind some LMS wall.

@KCd, well, course listings no longer give links to faculty pages, but only the the "LMS"... and/so students don't realize that anyone might be doing anything outside the "LMS"?

@paulgarrett  I see. It's true that on my course homepages within the university's LMS I place copies of my course notes rather than use a direct link to their original location on my own website, but I also did that back when my course homepages were on my own website.

The other answerers have covered most of the reasons. Elaborating on two problem areas that I find personally compelling:
University administrators and history of this technology.
I started maintaining a personal web page around 1995. I was quite excited about it, adding material as I saw fit. Quickly started using it as a channel for distributing information and material related to my courses as well. The pages were crude (basic HTML of the era), but they were A) easy to maintain, and B) got the job done. Many colleagues in Computer Science, Physics and Math did the same (maybe STEM fields were quick to adopt this). One could learn enough HTML in a few hours. Over the years I added more and more stuff. After a 3 hours course on Perl I even added a crude Q&A window on the course page, but the students were not really interested, and they disallowed CGIs (the first blow). But it has gotten progressively worse.

Some smart guy started tooting for Moodle and such. They had some leverage at the administration, university digital services in particular. After all, we are talking about people who never taught a single course, but instead concentrated on demanding things like: uniform appearance, hiding content from outsiders. And because they weren't themselves doing the teaching, they had the time to press their agenda. Ridiculous. Pages of colleagues/friends from universities across the country - all out of sight. What a blow!
Then came the day the tech staff simply pulled down all the course pages on university HTML server, and declared that to be for personal pages only. A few dozen angry teachers were left in a limbo. I complained, and was given the address of that in-your-face "how did we do today" -page. I complained to the dean, as did many others. Soon enough both the deans of science and engineering schools made angry phone calls to the head of digital services, who presumably knew nothing about what his underlings had pulled off. Anyway, those web-pages were returned. But I could no longer rely on anything I kept their to be safe from whims of those bureaucrats. I had no choice but learn basic Moodle.
At the same time those young tyros started making demands that all the personal web pages need to be converted to Word Press instead of the familiar vanilla HTML. They would even include a link to a starter guide. You know, the one where it explained how anyone who has spend a decade learning UNIX can install it on their server. No local support would be given.

SCREW THEM!
TL;DR;

I have no desire to learn a completely new system for writing a web page every few years. That's not what I'm here for.
Keeping both Google and Microsoft (and Meta) from collecting personal information is too much work as it is, these changes make it worse.


I don't feel great about posting a rant like this. You can probably guess that the underlying sentiment has been brewing for a long time. Judging from the votes I'm not the only person feeling this way.
In the interest of fairness I would welcome an answer/comment from some university web administrator (or some such). Admittedly this answer may not be very conducive to a dialogue like that. But lack of dialogue from their side made the problem significantly worse than it needed to be.  Maybe that ship sailed :-(

+100 if I could.

My Why I Have My Own Web Site page says, in part, "Then, in August, 2011, the people who run the university web site apparently decided that teaching and learning would take a back seat to other uses of the web. They moved all the faculty material to a different server, with no notice, four days before the start of fall classes. All the search engine links broke, which was bad. Even worse, all the links in my distance learning courses broke. All that breakage could have been avoided by installing some "redirect" commands on the Web server, but they chose not to do that. {sigh}"

@CaptainEmacs: offer a bounty?

@JW Can I give the poster the bounty directly or how would I do that?

@CaptainEmacs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

@DanielR.Collins I do not think that addresses my intention. I did not wish to put a bounty on the question, but reward the response (and this is not my question, so I do not think I have a say where the bounty goes to).

@CaptainEmacs: "You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it...  After the bounty ends... Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer."

My experience has been that many professors had their students make their websites using Dreamweaver or something similar, then the student would graduate, replace their laptop, or lose their software license. Years later when the professor wants to update their website they don't know how. (Or sometimes they host a website on an unpatched personal machine connected to the network, causing a security hazard.) Having a standardized, centralized system such as WordPress means I.T. doesn't have to support and secure every custom option for every professor.

@jeffronicus I'm sure concerns like that were behind some decisions. For example, I understand, why our I.T. pulled the plug off user written cgi-scripts. But I'm not net savvy enough to know exactly what kind of a security hazard my HTML3 pages form? And should they then not provide tools converting my structure of one html file (plus supporting links, images and pdf-documents) per course into WP?

I had to check it. I'm only using HTML1 commands :-) Not sure I want to learn anything more difficult.

Effort and reward.
Effort: Updating a website takes effort. Maybe a lot of effort (see Daniel's excellent answer), maybe a little less. But not everyone knows how to update their site, and there's no real reason to expect them to know how. Why should a professor of (say) history know HTML code and so on?
Reward: There isn't much. What does a professor gain from an updated site? Probably what changes the most often is publications and that can go on a CV, or, for other people who want to know what a professor has published, there's always Google Scholar.
Professors get paid to do research, teach, and win grants. In their spare time (hah!) they probably would rather go fishing, or read a novel, or spend time with their families than update websites.

What does a professor gain from an updated site? Don't research interests change over time? Prospective students might decide to contact/not contact depending on the research interests listed on the webpage.

@Allure - I suspect many professors think too many prospective students contact them already.

@Allure The general theme of the research typically doesn't change. If a professor talks about neurology on their webpage, they're not likely to have switched to plant pathology. The details may have changed (e.g. researching Parkinson's instead of Alzheimer's), but you can gauge that from recent publications. (And they're unlikely to be public about unpublished work, even if they're actively updating the webpage.) -- If you really want to know details about potential prospective projects, you need to contact the professor in any case.

One "reward" is that you can encourage uptake of your research by e.g. providing the code to reproduce the results in a paper, or software toolboxes implementing your methods, or on-line demonstrations (using javascript perhaps) of your research methods so that other researchers can have a play with them without any effort being required.  The research can be more than just the paper.  I also use my site for my hobby programming output (much more fun than fishing!)

I think a potential grad student would, after looking at a website, look for what the professor has done lately,, especially if the web page looks out of date.

True, but I think potential grad students are a small minority of the visitors (and they also may enjoy using the demos and other dynamic content).  It is a pity that I have time for dynamic content creation or to make the site look "up-to-date" (which I personally dislike), but not both (not that I have that much time for either these days).

@DikranMarsupial This only really seems to apply to software people. I tend to find that such people are much more likely to have more up to date websites (at least the "tools" or "software" sections) than other professors.

@IanSudbery indeed CS profs are probably also more likely to generate dynamic content which needs more freedom than content mangement systems (including things like squarespace) can easily provide - in my case most of it was written so that biologists could have a play with the bioinformatics applications I was working on.

@Peter Flom a prospective PhD applicant can look at the updated status of the professor regarding not having any active open positions and not waste his money (and effort) by applying and listing him as a potential advisor?

@R.M. well research interests can be obscure to people who aren't expert. For example, it's not a priori clear to me that Parkinson's and Alzheimer's are even related (I know they're both ailments of the brain, but I don't know if e.g. research that cures one will also cure the other). Furthermore professors often publish a lot of papers, so it's impractical to check all of them in detail; a reasonable question one might ask is "what recent paper are you most proud of" and that is something one would again rely on the website to say.

The real question is: Why do professors have a website in the first place?
Consider the value proposition -- and then how priorities and technologies change through their career and you get a recipe for out of date sites.
Professors have a website to 1) convey information to students and 2) advertise themselves.

A professor may have a website to post course related files.  This used to be the only way to provide supplementary materials and notes to accompany your course.  Their university may have adopted some centralized course management software (Blackboard, Moodle, etc.) and now require that such information is shared via that site -- which is only accessible to students.  Consequently, the old course pages are left to wither.

A new professor has many reasons to advertise themselves and their lab.  They want to attract good grad students and provide information about their work to potential sponsors.  They want their papers as accessible as possible (to drive citations).  These things (students, funding, papers) are all very important to the professor until they go through the promotion and tenure process.  After that, their need to self promote diminishes and you are left with old websites that are left to wither.


In addition to adopting course management systems, departments, colleges, and universities are fond of introducing and changing policies.  This often follows a familiar pattern.

No policy, motivated faculty make their own website as needed.
Administration (at some level) decides that the faculty need more web presence, so they institute a policy that all faculty shall create a page.  They provide a template with minimal information that is updated by a university webmaster.  They discourage the use of a personal page.  The institution page has minimal useful information.
Soon the administration drops funding for the webmaster, so the 'official' site starts to rot, but the policy remains in place.
This cycle repeats at different levels of administration.  In all cases, the faculty are prevented from making the website something personal, topical, and useful to people in their field.  Any motivation for developing and maintaining a website is destroyed.


In my area, people self-host their own papers/preprints and notes that don't quite warrant formal publication. It's really useful for the research process to have someone's output on a certain topic all in one place!

Most academics have more things to complete than they have time to complete them.
Some of this work is stuff they're immensely interested in doing (e.g. carrying out work on their key research topics); some of it is stuff they're interested in (e.g. keeping up with the latest research in their and related fields); some of it is stuff that is absolutely mandatory and has hard deadlines (e.g. teaching, marking, some admin); some of is required to keep their work going and has hard deadlines (e.g. applying for grants); some of it is important to keep their work going to a good standard (e.g. preparing and updating course slides); and then you get stuff which would be nice to do and has no hard deadlines (e.g. updating a website).
Which things do you think are most likely to get put off?

The question should be

Why are so many professors' websites out of date?

and the answer, somewhat tongue-in-cheek is: Because nobody has updated them. The reason for that is, generally, that people do what is fun and rewarding, which mostly excludes updating websites.

I don't think we need another answer that says "they have other things to do" except is also short.

@AzorAhai-him- Yeah, point taken. The additional angle I wanted to bring was that this is a general issue, nothing to see here.

My website never goes out of date. That would require that I have one in the first place...

@JonCuster you don't have a LinkedIn profile?

@Allure - not at all. I have the job I want until I retire.

As others have already said, this is not something that is entirely under our control. Depending on the institution, there may - or may not - be a person who is specifically tasked with keeping these pages/sites current. Otherwise, it can easily be more than a few years between updates. We, for example, have seen recent staff turnover in our department since the pandemic, and we - only just this week - have identified the person to whom we must now submit our updated CVs. That said, many of us keep our information up-to-date via other means - i.e., Google Scholar, LinkedIn, ResearchGate, etc.

Given most of the previous "complications" and issues already considered, many scholars tend to use nowdays other "technologies" instead, that are much easier to use. Among them I can see (my case) active presence in "social networks" such as Twitter / LinkedIN mostly. Once you register, it is much easier to publish anything related to your work there, and secondly, the platform's algorithm will take care that you get content you like so that you remain there.

Many good answers, one thing I would add is just the idea of pasr historical biases. People who have taught since 1996 are less likely to have their own GitHub. Compare them to young aspiring people in econometrics (like me, or those in software engineering), we (the newer blood) have much much more incentive to want to learn how to make our own website, and maintain it.
Back in ye olden days, you either didn't have a website (since presumably it was rare to have your own) or yours was maintained by those at the university, which as others have mentioned comes with bureaucracy.
